# Where can PT-6 engine series starter-Generator diagrams be found?

Tags: engine, accessory-drives

Wondering if anyone can direct me to the spec sheet, diagrams, and breakdowns of a typical Starter-Generator for a PT-6, say a PT6-66 series or similar. And also who are the major manufacturers of such units for turbo-props? Thank you.

Comment: Have you asked [Pratt & Whitney](https://www.pw.utc.com/) for this information?

Comment: Do you have a link or a contact list for anyone in Pratt & Whitney who would supply this information to an outsider? And why would they do that...?!

Comment: I don't have a contact but I did provide a link to the P&W website in my comment above. You haven't said why you want the information. If you don't think P&W will help you then I doubt anyone else will. It may be covered by non-disclosure agreements, and almost certainly by copyright.